# Print characters from a file but omit characters in parentheses

Tags: c, sum, hex

How would one go about parsing through characters inputted from a file and then printing those characters except for ones inside of parentheses? For example, if the file inputted "dog house (bird yellow) blue car", how would I make it to output dog house  blue car?

```
while ((character = fgetc(fileHandle)) != EOF)
{
 while (character != '(')
 {
  printf("%c", character);
 }
}
```

Comment: show the code that you have already tried

Comment: Is there some way to set up sentinel values that allow me so step back into a loop when 2 conditions have been met? So when '(" is inputted I step out of the loop and when ')' is inputted I step back in but without printing ')'?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no nested parentheses, you could do

```
int in_parens = 0;
while ((character = fgetc(fileHandle)) != EOF)
{
    if (character == '(')
        in_parens = 1;
    else if (character == ')')
        in_parens = 0;
    else if (in_parens == 0)
        printf("%c", character);
}
```

Comment: (you can always use a simple stack and *push* each `'('` and *pop* each `')'` and then if *stack-empty* - `in_parens = 0;` -- or you can just use a counter (initialized zero) and increment for each `'('` and decrement for each `')'` and `if (counter == 0) in_parens = 0;`)

Answer (score 0):

How about this....

```
 while ((character = fgetc(fileHandle)) != EOF){
   if(character == '('){
     while((character = fgetc(fileHandle)) != ')') //find the closing parentheses
        ; //do nothing
     character = fgetc(fileHandle); //get next input character
   }

 printf("%c",character);
}
```